# Cakephp 3.7.4 Auth hash password Not working

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0, cakephp-3.7

I am trying to implement auth login and register cakephp 3.7.4

I have used following code for UsersController add method

```
public function add()
{
    $this->viewBuilder()->setLayout('login');
    $user = $this->Users->newEntity();
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $post = $this->request->getData();
        $post['created'] = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        $post['modified'] = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        $user = $this->Users->patchEntity($user, $post);
        if ($this->Users->save($user)) {
            $this->Flash->success(__('The user has been saved.'));
            return $this->redirect(['action' => 'login']);
        }
        $this->Flash->error(__('Unable to add the user.'));
    }
    $this->set('user', $user);
}
```

But it can't save password in Hash Format

I have also create entity and used this function but it also not helped me

```
 class User extends Entity
 {
   protected $_accessible = [
     'email' => true,
    'password' => true
  ];
 protected $_hidden = [
    'password'
 ];
 protected function _setPassword($password){
  return(new  DefaultPasswordHasher)->hash($password);
 }
}
```

Comment: "Can't save" is very vague. Do you get an error message? Does it save the password unhashed? Does it save a blank password?

Comment: @GregSchmidt No, it will not generating error. It will save same password we entered

Comment: `debug($user);` after the `newEntity` call. What's the type? Is it the expected `User` entity, or a generic object?

Comment: Why are you adding modifies and created on your own? Try adding TimestampBehavior to your UsersTable. I‘d recommend using a debugger, like xdebug and setting a breakpoint in your _setPassword().

Comment: @Seb Is this is main reasons for password hash

Comment: I'd do a `debug($post)` just before `patchEntity()` is called and a `debug($password)` before the return statement in the `_setPassword()` function to check which data is patched and if the setter is being called.

Comment: @Simon I have done both , result is same its doesn't encrypt password

Comment: So the `debug($password)` is called in the setter function and the debug value (should be plain password) is printed?

Comment: @Simon Yes plain password is printed. Can you please enter answer with correct code. So that I can test it by implementing

Answer (score 0):

I installed a fresh Cake 3.7.4 installation, baked a `users` table, `users` controller and `users` table/entity. The following code for the User Class successfully hashed the password before it is written to the database. Please compare it with your code.

```
namespace App\Model\Entity;

use Cake\Auth\DefaultPasswordHasher;
use Cake\ORM\Entity;

class User extends Entity
{
    protected $_accessible = [
        'email' => true,
        'password' => true,
        'modified' => true,
        'created' => true
    ];
    protected $_hidden = [
        'password'
    ];

    protected function _setPassword($password)
    {
        return (new DefaultPasswordHasher())->hash($password);
    }
}
```

Comment: Not working public function add()
    {
        $this->viewBuilder()->setLayout('login');
  $this->loadModel('Users');
  $user = $this->Users->newEntity();
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
   $user = $this->Users->patchEntity($user, $this->request->data);
            if ($this->Users->save($user)) {
                $this->Flash->success(__('The user has been saved.'));
                return $this->redirect(['action' => 'login']);
            }
            $this->Flash->error(__('Unable to add the user.'));
        }
        $this->set('user', $user);
    }

Answer (score 0):

Just use parenthesis around `DefaultPasswordHaser()`:

```
return(new  DefaultPasswordHasher())->hash($password);
```